Are there macros for identifying if I'm using Wayland or X11?
I'm currently working on a project and, for learning, I want to write myself the windowing system with platform specific code.
So, I use the preprocessor to know at compile time which platform I'm on but I don't know how to identify the windowing system on Linux. I really need this because X11 and Wayland applications are not compatible; therefore, I'll have to write different files.
Here is my file with the preprocessor options that I found on this site:
// Windows OS
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
  #define PLATFORM_WINDOWS 1
// Linux OS
#elif defined(__linux__)
  #define PLATFORM_LINUX 1
  #if defined(WAYLAND)
    #define LINUX_ON_WAYLAND
  #elif defined(X11)
    #define LINUX_ON_X11
  #endif
// Unix OS
#elif defined(__unix) || defined(__unix__)
  #define PLATFORM_UNIX 1
// Mac OS
#elif defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)
  #define PLATFORM_MACOS
// Unknown OS
#else
  #error "Unknown platform."
#endif

As you can see, I've put placeholders for WAYLAND and X11 but, is there a way to have a system like this working?

The key is abstractions. Put everything not depending on the underlying display system (X11 or Wayland) in a separate library, everything depending on X11 in one library, and everything depending on Wayland in a third library. Make the interfaces (API) the same for both libraries. Then you create a small and simple glue program, and set up the build system to link with either the X11 or the Wayland library. Optionally, make the display system libraries dynamic (.so files) and the glue program loads them at runtime. Using macros like that will just make your code an unmaintainable mess.

How could a macro know? They're evaluated at compile time, but one or the other is in use at runtime. Usually build systems are running in isolated environments in use in serious environments (like Linux distro build farms) that don't have GUI access in the first place. Decisions about which optional dependencies to include, then, are managed with tools like autoconf; there's some automated selection based on which headers are installed, but beyond that you have options being passed to command line tools with humans building packages with configuration explicitly selecting options.

You could use a system along the lines of autoconf to determine whether the X11 or Wayland headers are available (separate from and prior to running the build).  If you have access to C23 everywhere that's relevant, perhaps you can use the new __has_include(headername) to decide what you're using — probably testing for the main Wayland header and assuming Wayland if it is present, and testing for the main X11 header, assuming X11 if it is present, and complaining if neither is available on Linux.

That you're imagining selecting between Wayland and X11 at build time implies that you must be planning on having source supporting both.  In that case, build both, and select between them at runtime.  There is a variety of ways to do that.  Alternatively, just choose one.  There's no law that your software has to support every conceivable system configuration.  Especially if this is a personal project, as it seems to be.  And if your choice is X, then you can probably still run that on top of Wayland, using an appropriate X server.

@Someprogrammerdude That's already what I did. Inspired by Travis Vroman and his Kohi game engine (link), I have an interface in a header platform.h and then the implementation for each OS has his own subfolder. But to know which subfolder to use the code definitions for compilation, i use header guards like  #ifdef PLATFORM_*** [...] #endif. If you have better ideas, you're welcomed.

@JohnBollinger As explained in my comment above, I use a kind of interface for my implementation. Therefore, how can I choose at runtime which implementation ? I know there is the environment variable called XDG_SESSION_TYPE, would using a command like system("echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE") be enough ?

@JonathanLeffler I'm on arch (btw) so yes I'm currently working with C23 (because I know that this project will be a hobby for years therefore I want to use C23 because on the long-run I will be happy to have all those new features). It would be a tool working at compile time or at runtime ? Is there any advantage between doing this at compile time or runtime ? And, does my solution above using XDG_SESSION_TYPE would be less error-prone ?

I'm not sure that there's an advantage to the __has_include mechanism; I've not yet used it for anything, but it exists.  I am inclined to prefer some sort of configuration phase (autoconf is the best known — and probably most hated — but it's far from being the only one, and may be overkill for you).  I'm not sure about the relative merits of compile time vs runtime determination of which windowing system to use.  In the transitional period (the next decade or so) while Wayland vies for usage over X11, runtime might be better — build both if your machines have both development setups.

Testing will be an issue — you'll need to switch between X11 and Wayland somehow, either by restarting the machine or by having multiple machines, some with X11 and some with Wayland.

The goal is a bit vague: x11 can be used with different API (xlib or xcb bindings), there’s also xwayland to run x11 apps under wayland, and so on.

I think I found two good enough solutions.
The first one works at compile time : just manually put a flag like -DBUILDING_WITH_X11 or -DBUILDING_WITH_WAYLAND and then check that at compilation there is only one flag defined. Example of my previous code with the change :
[...]
// Linux OS
#elif defined(__linux__)
  #define PLATFORM_LINUX 1
  #if defined(BUILDING_WITH_X11) && defined(BUILDING_WITH_WAYLAND)
    #error "You can't build for x11 and Wayland at the same time."
  #elif !defined(BUILDING_WITH_X11) && !defined(BUILDING_WITH_WAYLAND)
    #error "You need to define at least one windowing protocol to use."
  #endif
[...]

The second one works at runtime. It uses the command secure_getenv() from stdlib.h (with _GNU_SOURCE extension) which retrieve the value of a environment variable as a string. Therefore, i can use this with conditions to choose what functions I use :
if (strcmp(secure_getenv("XDG_SESSION_TYPE"), "wayland") == 0) {
    printf("We're on wayland.\n");
} else if (strcmp(secure_getenv("XDG_SESSION_TYPE"), "x11") == 0) {
    printf("We're on X11.\n");
} else {
    printf("wtf ?\n");
}

(Note : before any comment on this, I prefer to explicitely write the value we want to get when it's not a simple true false and here, as in a lot of std libraries, 0 is the equivalent of true which is annoying)
I really don't know which one is the best. Instinctively, the first one seems the easiest and I saw big programs (like glfw) have a build different for x11 and wayland (now, since glfw3.4, there is no glfw-x11 or glfw-wayland, it's just the same package) so I don't have to feel ashamed for not doing the biggest cross-platform perfect thing of all time.
Anyway, if people have remarks, I'll be very happy to change my mind and, at the contrary, i will mark that as my solution.
